# Why can a double sum be rearranged like this?

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{r = 1}^n \sum_{p=1}^n A_{j,p}A_{p,r}A_{r,k}=\sum_{p = 1}^n \sum_{r=1}^n A_{j,p}A_{p,r}A_{r,k}$$

Would reviewing double sums help me to avoid asking questions like this?

Does anybody know of a good source I can use to learn properties of double sums like this?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that addition is commutative.  More generally,
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n c_{i,j} = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m c_{i,j}.$$
Just think of adding up the elements of an $m \times n$ matrix either row-wise or column-wise.

Answer (score 1):

A good introduction answering many of this and  related  questions  is provided in chapter 2: *Sums* of  *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by R.L. Graham, D.E.  Knuth  and O.  Patashnik. Double sums are  treated in  section  2.4  *Multiple Sums*.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two summation indices, namely $r$ and $p.$ Hence you may think of the terms of the sum as arranged in a rectangular array $(p,r)$ of order $n×n$

On LHS we vary $p$ first and fix $r.$ Then we vary $r.$ This means for each column, we add all its components, and then add all the column-sums. On RHS the reverse is done; we vary $r$ first, fixing $p.$ Then vary $p.$ This means for each fixed row we add all its components, them add all such sums. Of course we get the same result however we choose to add. Thus, $\text{LHS}=\text{RHS}.$